# Using the Drupal commerce module for super simple single page checkout for one item

Tags: drupal, e-commerce, drupal-commerce

There are a mass of options when it comes to customizing the Drupal commerce module.

What modules do I need to enable for a super simple checkout that looks like this (all on the same page):

- Single Item, with a few variations which modify the price (Is this better to do with multiple items? Ultimately I want RULES To publish nodes based on what is purchased.)
- Credit card info / checkout with Paypal
- Checkout

Comment: This module it helps: http://drupal.org/project/commerce_express_checkout
Convert your checkout process in one express page

Answer (score 0):

The best advice I could give is don't use Commerce just yet, it's not mature enough. The base modules are (I believe) out of beta now but there are so many contributed modules that aren't finished yet or are currently unstable.

Have you come across the [Ubercart module](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart) by any chance? It is also dependant on and heavily integrated with Rules, and a lot of contributed modules are available.

For your purposes you could use Ubercart to define a single product category to which you add all of your products, and use the attributes module that's included to add differing price options for each. Paypal integration is also built right in.